# [Selenium][geckodriver] How to change firefox profile preference fields like "security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled"

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

**geckodriver Version**

0.16.1

**Firefox Version**

53.0.2 (32-bit)

**What happens:**

When I try to automate login on an unsafe page, the firefox opens a new tab "https://support.mozilla.org/1/firefox/53.0.2/WINNT/pt-PT/insecure-password".

How can I disable this? I think that property "security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled" is related to this behavior but i don't know how i could disable it by python code.

I try the following code but without success:

```
[...]
firefox_driver = path_drivers + "geckodriver.exe"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", False)
return webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver, firefox_profile=profile)
```

The preference doesn't change, remains with True value on about:config.

Any idea?

Best regards,

Ruben Santos

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.

From the version 0.11 of geckodriver is possible to change firefox preferences by the moz:firefoxOptions capability instead of change profile settings.

```
{
    "capabilities": {
        "alwaysMatch": {
            "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                "binary": "/usr/local/firefox/bin/firefox",
                "args": ["--no-remote"],
                "prefs": {
                    "dom.ipc.processCount": 8
                },
                "log": {
                    "level": "trace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way i was able to change the "security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled" with this solution:

```
[...]
firefox_driver = path_drivers + "geckodriver.exe"
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
#To disable insecure-password tab by support firefox
firefox_options = { "moz:firefoxOptions" : { "prefs" : { "security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled" : False } } }
firefox_capabilities["alwaysMatch"] = firefox_options
return webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver, capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found simpler solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled', False)
profile.set_preference('security.insecure_password.ui.enabled', False)
driver = Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```